# How to list tags in remote GitHub repo

Tags: git, github

How can I list the `git tag`s in a remote repository hosted in GitHub, without cloning it?

I am hoping for a simple command I can run from the command line, without SSH keys.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%22list+tags%22+%22remote+repository%22

Comment: `git ls-remote --tags URL`